# Explanation on Descartes' statement

Tags: philosophy-of-mind

"I think, therefore I am." Will anybody explain to me as clearly as possible what this statement actually mean?

Comment: Can you explore the context and motivations of the question a little more here? What have you been reading or studying that's made this an interesting problem? What hypotheses have you formed and what has your research uncovered so far?

Comment: You can begin reading *SEP* entries on [René Descartes](http://plato.stanford.edu/entries/descartes/) and [Descartes' Life and Works](http://plato.stanford.edu/entries/descartes-works/) and [Descartes' Epistemology](http://plato.stanford.edu/entries/descartes-epistemology/)

Answer (score 4):

Descartes set himself a project --to doubt all things that could possibly be doubted.  Even after discarding all the evidence of his senses, he was left with the conviction that his own existence was an indisputable fact he could apprehend and verify directly.

In other words, even if he was deceived about all the details of his existence, he had to exist in order to even be deceived.  Thus *I think, therefore I am.*  In the Cartesian view, the self-recognition of the thinking mind is the foundation of all real knowledge.

Comment: Is this thing true even for animals?

Comment: @AaKASH - Taken by itself, *I think therefore I am* is only valid for you, the thinker.  You can't assume that any other person --or animal --is thinking or even exists, no matter what appearances indicate.

Comment: @AaKASH you can only measure by yourself, as others might not exist.

Comment: Also.  This assumes that Descartes statement had merit.  Both science and modern philosophy (not to mention Buddhism) strongly point to the inaccuracy of his position - specifically the notion that there is one single thing that is the "I" - or that the "mind is like a little man within".